# How to test Test version app in AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

is there any concepts for beta version app submit to the App Store, i'm searching in google, i didn't get any point.

please inform me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Apple do not allow you to upload any Beta version of App on the Appstore. It is against the app submission guidelines.

For more information, Check this question in SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722428/app-store-rejects-on-2-9-apps-that-are-beta-demo-trial-or-test-versi